# Why wouldn't `new int[x]{}` be valid?

Tags: c#, arrays, monodevelop, opensuse

In MonoDevelop I have the following code which compiles:

```
int[] row = new int[indices.Count]{};
```

However, at run-time, I get:

> Matrix.cs(53,53): Error CS0150: A
>   constant value is expected (CS0150)
>   (testMatrix)

I know what this error means and forces me to then resize the array:

```
int[] row = new int[indices.Count]{};
Array.Resize(ref row, rowWidth);
```

Is this something I just have to deal with because I am using MonoDevelop on Linux? I was certain that under .Net 3.5 I was able to initialize an array with a variable containing the width of the array. Can anyone confirm that this is isolated? If so, I can report the bug to bugzilla.

Comment: The problem is probably because you're mixing array initialization and object initialization.  Remove the `{}` and you should be fine. Also, I tried to init this array in gsharp on OpenSuse11.2 and it fails immediately with the `{}` included.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You can't mix array creation syntax with object initialization syntax. Remove the `{ }`.**

When you write:

```
int[] row = new int[indices.Count];
```

You are creating a new array of size `indices.Count` initialized to default values.

When you write:

```
int[] row = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

You are creating an array and then initializing it's content to the values [1,2,3,4]. The size of the array is inferred from the number of elements. It's shorthand for:

```
int[] row = new int[4];
row[0] = 1;
row[1] = 2;
row[2] = 3;
row[3] = 4;
```

**The array is still first initialized to defaults**, this syntax just provides a shorthand to avoid havind to write those extra assignments yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The following code fails to compile for the same reason on Windows/.NET/LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] row = new int[indices.Count]{};
    row[2] = 10;
    row.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class indices {
    public static int Count = 5;
}
```

However, removing the object initialisation from the declaration (`{}`) makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, if you want to declare an empty array the syntax should be:

> int[] row = new int[indices.Count];

Answer (score 0):

Because when you to use use array initialization syntax AND specify the size of the array

```
int[] arr = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

The size of the array is superfluous information. The compiler can infer the size from the initialization list. As others have said, you either create empty array:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
```

or use the initialization list:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
```